# How to do common operations with HDFS files using fs.HadoopFileSystem?

Tags: python-3.x, hdfs, pyarrow

I need to do some ordinary operations with HDFS directories using python3.
Such as **`mkdir`**, **`chmod`**, **`chown`**, **`test`** if dir exists.

I try to use pyarrow, because it's official python client.

So, I looked throw [new API documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem), and couldn't find any useful methods.
The usage of the [legacy HDFS API](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems_deprecated.html) allowed to do it, but it is deprecated.

Could anyone answer, how to do operations that I mentioned, using new API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `pyarrow.HadoopFileSystem.mkdir` is [`pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.create_dir`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.create_dir)

There is no of `pyarrow.HadoopFileSystem.test` but there is [`pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.get_file_info`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.html#pyarrow.fs.HadoopFileSystem.get_file_info)

There is no equivalent for `chown` or `chmod`.  The new filesystems API has been motivated by "what is the minimum set of operations needed for higher level Arrow modules? (e.g. the datasets API)".  Every method added to the new API has to be added to each of the child implementations and most other filesystems have their own python bindings anyways.

Have you considered the standalone [hdfs](https://pypi.org/project/hdfs/) package?

Comment: Thank you for fast replying. Yes, I considered this package as alternative, but thought the pyarrow better choice, because it's package from apache.
Now I guess, hdfs package would be more suitable for me. Thank you.